# Creating Python Function to Iterate over List/DataFrame (VIF)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, statsmodels

I have a dataset and I want to select the subset of variables with VIF(Variance Inflation Factor) smaller than a certain threshold. My idea was to calculate the VIF for every variable, then take out the variable for the highest value (if its higher than a certain threshold), recalculate the VIF for every remaining variable and repeat the process until there is no VIF higher than the treshold.

There is no novel idea in this approach but I couldn't get past a certain point to make a function to automatize this process in Python.

x is the dataset with the target variable dropped

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant

x_vif = add_constant(x)

vif = pd.DataFrame([variance_inflation_factor(x_vif.values, i) for i in range(x_vif.shape[1])], index=x_vif.columns)
```

The vif could also be a List. So, is there any package that does that automatically or could you give me an idea how to create this function ?

I found a R library (thinXwithVIF) that could do that automatically, but I couldn't make rpy2 work with the python version that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what would make sense is to remove the variable with the highest vif in each round, subset the dataframe and stop when all variables are lower than your threshold. I don't think vif would be be-all-and-end-all and you really have to look at the data to decide what to include etc.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars')

x_vif = data.data.iloc[:,1:]
y = data.data['mpg']

thres = 10

while True:
    Cols = range(x_vif.shape[1])
    
    vif = np.array([variance_inflation_factor(x_vif.values, i) for i in Cols])
    if all(vif < thres):
        break
    else:
        Cols = np.delete(Cols,np.argmax(vif))
        x_vif = x_vif.iloc[:,Cols]
```